# Change elements on different positions within a list

Tags: list-manipulation, formatting

How can I change the elements of a list, say on positions 
`{{1, 4}, {3, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 4}}` in one go?

Take this list for example:

```
In:= (m = Array[RandomInteger[9] &, {4, 4}]) // TableForm

Out= 0  6   2   8
     3  8   8   0
     3  7   4   1
     4  8   2   4
```

This is how I want to the elements on the specified positions to change.

```
m[[1, 4]] = Style[m[[1, 4]], 14, Bold, Blue];

m // TableForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The result is that the 8 in the last element of the first row is now blue and bold (and bigger to stand out).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`MapAt` is probably the most direct:

```
MapAt[Style[#, Bold, Blue] &, m, {{1, 4}, {3, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 4}}] // TableForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However this makes a copy of the table rather that modifying it in place.  You could use `m = MapAt[ . . . ]` but this still uses additional memory.

Although it may not meet the requirement of "in one go" doing your `Part` assignment for each element is I believe the most efficient method:

```
(m[[##]] = Style[m[[##]], Bold, Blue]) & @@@
   {{1, 4}, {3, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 4}};

m // TableForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[J. M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) remarks that this method would be better implemented using `Scan`.  That is true if you are doing many replacements as the list built by using `@@@` takes memory.  With `Scan` it would look like this:

```
(m[[##]] = Style[m[[##]], Bold, Blue]) & @@ # & ~Scan~ 
   {{1, 4}, {3, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 4}};
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess both approaches can be used in many situations.

Comment: How did you make the pictures of the matrix?

Comment: @sjd You can use Szabolcs's image uploader palette for this. See [this link](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5/can-i-easily-post-images-to-this-site-directly-from-mathematica-yes) for more information and a download link.

Comment: I'd have used `Scan[]` myself instead of `Apply[]` for the second method...

Comment: @Heike Is there anyway to make "In" or "Out" a picture,of which the background is transparent not just white

Comment: @paradox2 I know you were not addressing me, but I'm interested.  What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Here is a site [A blog](http://www.matrix67.com/blog/archives/2907),you can see many pictures posted in this blog,and the background of these pictures is transparent,not just white.I am not sure if the author has used other softwares to achieve it. So is there any way by coding.I am not speaking English,and wish this time you can understand what I mean.

Comment: @paradox2 I understand now.  I don't believe it can be done for the "pixel perfect Windows version" because that uses Copy As Bitmap which doesn't support transparency.  For the "multiplatform" version (which can also be used on Windows) this should be simply a matter of inserting `Background -> None` into `Rasterize[target, "Image"];` and `ExportString[g, "PNG"];`.  However, you should contact Szabolcs to make the changes as I am not deeply familiar with his code.  "Upload SE transparent" would be a useful button in my opinion.

Comment: @paradox2 By the way, any additional questions about this should be made in the thread Heike linked above.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ah,I am still trying.And I will follow your advice next time,thanks for your answers.

Comment: @paradox2 and MrW I was going to make some other improvements as well, but actually it's the rasterization code that's the most difficult ...  I *think* it should be possible, at least in certain situations, using the method Mr Wizard mentioned.  Could you please file a bug [here](https://github.com/szhorvat/Mathematica.SE-utilities/issues), so I won't forget about it?

Comment: @Szabolcs, MrW: I've submitted a feature request, so it won't be forgotten. I'm looking forward to see the new upload palette!

Answer (score 2):

```
m = {{0, 6, 2, 8}, {3, 8, 8, 0}, {3, 7, 4, 1}, {4, 8, 2, 4}};

positions = {{1, 4}, {3, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 4}};
```

#### ReplaceAt

[`ReplaceAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAt.html) (introduced in Version 13.1) is a close sibling of `MapAt` and `ReplacePart`:

```
ReplaceAt[x_ :> Style[x, Bold, Blue], positions] @ m // MatrixForm
```

[image]

#### MapIndexed + ReplaceAll

```
MapIndexed[
 ReplaceAll[{Alternatives @@ positions :> 
   Style[#, Blue, Bold], _ -> #}] @ #2 &, m, {2}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Using `SubsetMap`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[1];
(m = Array[RandomInteger[9] &, {4, 4}]);
locs = {{1, 4}, {3, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 4}} 
{m, SubsetMap[Map[Style[#, Bold, Blue] &], m, locs]} // 
 Map[MatrixForm]
```

[image]